# CRUD Views For Many-Many Relationship, Checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first, checkbox

I am having a hard time trying to figure out what I need to do to get this to work. I'm learning ASP.NET MVC CodeFirst with EF. If I make a model I can simply add a controller for that model and add scaffolding to create views that automatically take care of CRUD. But now I have two models, Project and Category. They have a many to many relationship and database is designed correctly with the associative table without having to make a separate model for it. The code for the models is this....

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Testimonial { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
    }
}
```

So I add my controllers and do the scaffolding. I go in and create my categories just fine. But when it comes to my Projects/Create view, I would like to make it so that all the categories are displayed as checkboxes. Also, I would like to ensure that at least one category is selected before being able to submit the form to create a project. How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an example of using check boxes in a similar scenario, see **Adding Course Assignments to the Instructor Edit Page** in this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Actually I managed to get it to do what I wanted to do. But I skimmed through the link here and I'll definitely check it out because it looks like it does go over what my issue was. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to come back and say how great that link is you posted. I just went over it and it worked beautifully and way better than my implementation was. Been lookin' for somethin' like this for weeks. Thanks again!